# Twig : Unescape hexadecimal text

Tags: php, html, symfony, hex, twig

I try to secure email address on my website and I used the function (twig filter) below to encode it :

```
/**
 * The twig filter associated with this function is "encode_email"
 */
function encode_emailFilter($email) 
{ 
    $text = $email; 
    $text_encode = ''; 

    for ($x=0; $x < strlen($text); $x++) { 
        $text_encode .= '&#x' . bin2hex($text[$x]).';'; 
    } 

    return $text_encode; 
}
```

So, I encoded my email like this

```
{{ emailFromDatabase|encode_email }}
```

And on my HTML page, it shows

```
&#x73;&#x75;&#x70;&#x65;&#x72;&#x6d;&#x61;&#x72;&#x69;&#x6f;&#x40;&#x67;&#x6d;&#x61;&#x69;&#x6c;&#x2e;&#x63;&#x6f;&#x6d;
```

I tried to add "[raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)" to the filter but, I always get the same result

```
{{ emailFromDatabase|raw|encode_email }}
```

However, if I display directly the hexadecimal without wrapping it with `{{ }}`, the email address displays correctly

```
<span>&#x73;&#x75;&#x70;&#x65;&#x72;&#x6d;&#x61;&#x72;&#x69;&#x6f;&#x40;&#x67;&#x6d;&#x61;&#x69;&#x6c;&#x2e;&#x63;&#x6f;&#x6d;</span>

//Returns
supermario@gmail.com
```

So, what filter should I add to my twig variable to get it work?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put `raw` at the end:

`{{ emailFromDatabase|encode_email|raw }}`

Because you want:

- to take the variable
- encode it
- then display it without escaping

Comment: Thank you, it works. I should have thought about it :)